# How to tell if insert key has been held down

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keydown

I'm trying to capture certain keydown events in my application but only if no "control" keys have been held down at the same time. I don't want to run into issues with screen reader keyboard shortcuts. `Shift`, `Ctrl` and `Alt` are easy to check for because they're on the javascript event, but I also need to check for `Ins` and `Windows` keys as well as any Mac control keys.

This is what I've got so far and it works as expected, but my event is still triggered when `Ins` or `Windows` is held down.

```js
handleKeydown: function(event) {
  var comboKeyPressed = event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey || event.altKey;
  if(!comboKeyPressed && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.HOME) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.$('>ul>li:last').attr('tabindex', -1);
    this.$('>ul>li:first').attr('tabindex', 0).focus();
  } else if (!comboKeyPressed && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.END) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.$('>ul>li:first').attr('tabindex', -1);
    this.$('>ul>li:last').attr('tabindex', 0).focus();

  }
}
```

Is there a way to check for other control keys easily or do I need to capture those events and hold onto them in some global Boolean like `this.isInsertPressed`?

Comment: This answer is becoming dated. Please see below on how to use event.key instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var keysPressed = {};
var keys = { insert: 45 };    
$(window).keydown(function(e) { keysPressed[e.which] = true; });
$(window).keyup(function(e) { keysPressed[e.which] = false; });
```

And then later:

```
if (keysPressed[keys.insert]) {
    // insert key is currently down
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use `event.key` and modern JS!

*No number codes* anymore. You can check for <kbd>Insert</kbd> key directly.

```
let isInsertDown = false;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Insert") {
        isInsertDown = true;
    }
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Insert") {
        isInsertDown = false;
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: This is the proper answer, in terms of forward compatibility with browsers. See the deprecation note on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Answer (score 1):

Use **keycode** property in the `Event object`

```
if(event.keyCode === 45) // Insert Key
```

Comment: That will catch it when it's initially pressed, but it's still held down when `event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.HOME` and I need to not allow that to do anything.

Comment: The you would also need to keep a track of the keyup event and check if the previous key was released